# PhpStorm - Where can I see if I changed a file?

Tags: phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 2022.2 on Windows 10 with (Settings > Appearance > Theme) IntelliJ Light.
I dont use version controlling (git, svn etc.) in my project.

When I change a file I am used (from other editors) to see some change in the file tab, e.g. the color changes, or there is a "*" beside the filename.
In PhpStorm I don't see any changes in the file tab or else where, if I changed something in the file.
Where can I set this?

I looked through all settings, searched the net, but found only solutions concerning version control.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what other editors show the changes without being backed up by a source control? The IntelliJ editors do this and they also store local copies of the modified files periodically, independent of the presence of a source control repository.

Comment: @axiac As an example: Notepad++ -- if you open a file and make changes then the new/modified lines will have a color line on the gutter. If you save the file -- those lines will change the color indicating that the file had changes since it was opened (in this session). https://i.imgur.com/GPkfHLr.png GREEN -- already saved changes; ORANGE -- fresh changes since the last save.

Comment: @axiac How to show the same in PhpStorm when there is no VCS for this project? I'd love to see them in the gutter. AFAIK you need VCS here in JetBrains IDEs.

Comment: @LazyOne I guess you are right about PhpStorm. I didn't use it since 2018, probably I have wrong memories about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings (Preferences on macOS)`
2. `Editor | General | Editor Tabs`
3. Ensure that `Mark modified (*)` option is enabled

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-editor-tabs.html#appearance

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself, after searching again with better search words ;)
I found it on PhpStorm Help pages:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-editor-tabs.html#appearance

So the setting is in:

*Settings > Editor > General > Editor Tabs > Mark modified (*)*

And after checked it does what I expect :)